# Can Metal be used on a Mac Mini from 2011 if there is an eGPU?

Tags: macos

I have a Mac Mini from 2011. I noticed the GPU on the Mac is an Intel HD 3000 series, and thus doesn't support Metal on Mojave or above.

So, could I buy a Metal compatible GPU, a Thunderbolt 3 dock, and Apple's Thunderbolt 2 adaptor along with the cable, and use Metal support off the external GPU rather than the onboard graphics?

The Mac is currently running Big Sur with patches.

Comment: [According to Apple themselves](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208544) this could be done with a direct Thunderbolt 3 connection. But not clear if a Thunderbolt 2 connection would work. That said, look at [this discussion](https://egpu.io/forums/mac-setup/thunderbolt-2-fast-enough-to-handle-gpu/). It seems like it *might* work, but it seems kludgy.

Comment: The 2011 mini isn't TB2, it's only TB1.